# SharePoint 2013 Asynchronous event handler executing synchronously (under wpw3 instead of owstimer)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, asynchronous, w3wp, event-receiver

I created a custom list event handler using `Visual Studio 2013`, for `ItemAdded` and `ItemUpdated` events. I totally expected those to execute under `OWSTIMER.EXE` as I do not want to add load to `W3wp.exe`, since the actions I need to perform in the `ER` will be rather heavy. However, in debug mode I noticed that it would only hit my `Breakpoints` by attaching to the `W3wp.exe`. I even configured the event receiver to be asynchronous in the `XML` expecting this would force them to run under `OWSTimer` but no luck.
I strongly suspect this changed from `SP2010` to `SP2013`.
Could you guys please shed some light on this? Does anyone know whether both sync and async events execute under `w3wp` in `SP2013`?

Thanks in advance,

Martin.

Comment: For reference [Which process do event receivers run under?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27717/which-process-do-event-receivers-run-under)